# Problem with solving a system of differential equations within Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parameters

I'm triing to do this commands:

```
f1[t_] := s*(y[t] - x[t]);
f2[t_] := x[t]*(k - z[t]) - y[t];
f3[t_] := x[t]*y[t] - m*z[t];
system = {x'[t] == f1[t], y'[t] == f2[t], z'[t] == f3[t]};
ini = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, z[0] == 10};
Manipulate[
Module[{n = NDSolve[Join[system, ini], {x, y, z}, {t, 10, 100}]}, 
ParametricPlot3D[
Evaluate[{n[[1]][t], n[[2]][t], n[[3]][t]}], {t, 1, 100}]], {s, 2, 
10}, {m, 2, 10}, {k, 2, 10}]
```

And there is an Error:NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. Can you tell me, where i'm wrong?

Comment: The `Manipulate` variables must appear _explicitly_ in the body of the `Manipulate`.  This is not okay: `x:=a; Manipulate[x, {a,0,1}]`

Comment: The past version of this Notebook contained the right place of variables, but the error was the same

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`, then we have

```
f1[t_] := s*(y[t] - x[t]);
f2[t_] := x[t]*(k - z[t]) - y[t];
f3[t_] := x[t]*y[t] - m*z[t];
system = {x'[t] == f1[t], y'[t] == f2[t], z'[t] == f3[t]};
ini = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, z[0] == 10}; n = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[
  Join[system, ini], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {s, m, k}];


Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[n[s, m, k]], {t, 0, 100}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All], {s, 2, 10}, {m, 2, 10}, {k,
   2, 10}]
```

[image: Figire1]

The second option using `Module[]`

```
f1[t_] := s*(y[t] - x[t]);
f2[t_] := x[t]*(k - z[t]) - y[t];
f3[t_] := x[t]*y[t] - m*z[t];
system = {x'[t] == f1[t], y'[t] == f2[t], z'[t] == f3[t]};
ini = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, z[0] == 10};
Manipulate[
 Module[{n = 
    NDSolveValue[
     Join[system /. {s -> s1, m -> m1, k -> k1}, ini], {x[t], y[t], 
      z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]}, 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[n], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue]], {s1, 2, 10}, {m1, 2, 10}, {k1, 2, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: I'm so glad it's works! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ИванКрамойкин You're welcome!